# Underscore character in tizen wearbale 2.3.1 emulator not found

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I’m trying to find underscore character in watch emulator keyboard, but it is not visible on screen.Shift key is not working in emulator.So is there any way so I can type from system keyboard in emulator text field?

[image: Screenshot of emulator]

[image: Clicked on download button]

[image: After tapping finish button]

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks Iqbal - Could you please give more details on link from where you have downloaded (Circle) IME Double Keys keyboard and in IDE where can I find options “Sample”?

Comment: New Tizen Project > Online Sample if Tizen IDE / Sample if Tizen Studio

Comment: What is your update?

Comment: Sorry Iqbal,I was on leave so couldn’t reply.I tried it but Im not able to download that sample project.Once I click on download it never shows “Completion message” and i f I tap on finish button it is giving “Error occurred while creating new project. java.io.IOException”.So looking into it.On their site also it is not available-https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/sample/web/Input%20Method%20Editor/%28Circle%29_IME_Double_Keys?langredirect=1

Comment: Are you using Tizen Studio ?

Comment: No..Tizen  ide 2.4

Comment: See the picture of updated answer ... you have to download it by your IDE.

Comment: Please check newly added screenshots of my system.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this issue before. But i got a solution. 
I have installed a keyboard from online sample. From then i am using this keyboard. 
For this keyboard, From IDE goto

*New >Tizen Web Application> Online Sample >Input Method Editor> **(Circle) IME Double Keys***

[image]

Run this project to your desired emulator. 
Now you have to goto

*Emulator Settings>Text Input> Select IMEDoubleKey as input text*

Now you can use as the picture below.

You have to double-click on '-' key to type '_' (underscore) on Tizen Wearable emulator. See the picture.

[image]